# I get undefined when reading my response but there is a response in React.js

Tags: node.js, reactjs, axios

I can't figure it out, the answer comes in the network table but when I want to console.log it, this will display undefined. Do you have any idea why? I attach the pictures and the code.
[Here is a image with my codes and response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9POwI.png)

Here is the code - first one is where I send the response. As I said, it's going well on network tab, I get a 200 status.

```
export const getAccountStatus = async (req, res) => {
  const user = await User.findById(req.user._id).exec();
  const account = await stripe.accounts.retrieve(user.stripe_account_id);
  // console.log("user account retrieve", account);
  const updatedUser = await User.findByIdAndUpdate(
    user._id,
    {
      stripe_seller: account
    },
    { new: true }
  )
    .select("-password")
    .exec();
  console.log(updatedUser);
  res.send(updatedUser);
};
```

Here is the page where i want to console.log it:

```
const StripeCallback = ({ history }) => {
  const { auth } = useSelector(state => ({ ...state }));
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  useEffect(() => {
    if (auth && auth.token) accountStatus();
  }, [auth]);

  const accountStatus = async () => {
    try {
      const res = await getAccountStatus(auth.token);
      console.log(res);
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  };
  return <div>test</div>;
};
```

Ang here is the Axios.post (which is working well as I know):

```
export const getAccountStatus = async token => {
  await axios.post(
    `${process.env.REACT_APP_API}/get-account-status`,
    {},
    {
      headers: {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`
      }
    }
  );
};
```

Thank you!

Comment: `getAccountStatus` doesn't return anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`getAccountStatus` doesn't have a `return` statement, so `res` in `const res = await getAccountStatus(auth.token);` will always be undefined.

```
export const getAccountStatus = async token => {
  return axios.post(  // <----- added return
    `${process.env.REACT_APP_API}/get-account-status`,
    {},
    {
      headers: {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`
      }
    }
  );
};
```

Comment: Thank you buddy! Now I saw that I put the brackets there {}, 
without them it was a default return. Thanks again! It seems that they are beginner's problems.